# Calling a powershell function using a .bat file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I would like to know how to call a powershell function using a .Bat file.

I have this simple function:

(Script.ps1)

```
function testfunction
{
Write-Log "Calling from Bat file"
}
```

and I would like to call the function testfunction within the .Bat File.

powershell .\Script.ps1 ...

Comment: What's the reason for still using .bat files since you now have PowerShell?

Comment: The powershell file has a series of functions and it's located on shared folder.  A different batch file is located locally in each server.  The batch file needs to execute different functions depending on what each server needs thus the reason why the .bat file needs to call a different function depending on the server environment.  I am new to powershell so I figured this would be the easiest way for each server to manage itself.

Comment: I mean, use another PowerShell script instead of ancient .bat files.

Comment: great idea.  How can I do that?

Comment: Step 1: learn basic PowerShell.

Comment: Sure, .bat files are crusty and old, but they're still out there. It's heedless to assume they can always be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that there is a switch `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass` which allows the batch file to run using Powershell.  This works here, taken from the answer by vonPryz.

```
@echo off
:: Create a test script file
echo function test { write-host "Called from %~f0" } > s.ps1
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -command ". "%cd%\s.ps1"; test;"
del s.ps1
pause
```

Comment: thanks for the `...%cd%...`. i didn't know this yet.

Answer (score 3):

Start Powershell with `-command` switch, include the script and call the function. You need to dot source the script before its function can be called.

```
:: Create a test script file
C:\temp>echo function test { write-host "Called from .bat" } > c:\temp\s.ps1
C:\temp>powershell -command ". c:\temp\s.ps1; test;"
:: Output
Called from .bat
```

Also, take a look at [some samples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx).

Comment: This can be worked around I guess but by default in Windows 8 I receive this error: ---> . : File D:\abc\s.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

Comment: @foxidrive Set the execution policy as per the document you liked to?

Comment: The problem is that you can't give the advice to any person without also telling them that they have to change the execution policy.  It's great for a single machine but not for general scripting advice.

Comment: @foxidrive I don't quite follow your reasoning. Granted, the OP seems to be lacking basic Powershell skills. Thus extra hint about setting execution policy could be useful. Then again, the error message is quite clear and provides good advice how to change the policy should need be.

Comment: What I mean is that every solution where this technique is employed also needs a warning that it will not work unless further steps are taken.  There is also the likelihood that people in a corporate setting will not be able to disable security settings to make it work.  It's not an 'out of the box' technique that will run by itself and that makes it less useful for the class of people that ask questions and don't have technical knowledge.  Does that clarify what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old but I was recently trying to do this same thing and it took me a long time to find out what to do.  The answer is amazingly simple

In BatchFile (RunMe)

powershell -command ". Script.ps1; Set-SomeFunction %1 %2 %3 %4 %5"

Then you can call the batch like

RunMe -SomeParm val -SomeParm2 val -SomeSwitch -SomeBool $true

also, to run as admin

powershell -command "Start-Process -verb runas powershell" "'-noexit -command ". Script.ps1; Set-SomeFunction %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9'"

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like that:

```
powershell {Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted}
powershell.exe -executionpolicy ByPass ./script/powerhsell-script.ps1 %par1% %par2%
powershell {Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted}
```

Hope you need that :)

Answer (score 0):

I've done it using

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file ".\Write_date.ps1"
```

Seems similar to what others have written but I'm not sure what vonPryz meant by needing the dot source the script before calling the script. The above worked on a Win7 with executionpolicy set to restricted.